# Display an error message if a php script breaks

Tags: php, error-handling

As the question suggests, I would like to display an error message when a php script breaks.
Suppose

```
$var = somefunction();
```

If somefunction has a code which breaks the script, then I want to return a custom message. Like

```
if($var <> true)
   //error message here
```

Also is there a timeout function which can detect maximum time execution and display the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `set_error_handler` and I think you need `debug_backtrace` function to use it inside your error handler function

You can read more here: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php
and 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

If you wanna just trigger error use : `trigger_error();`

Answer (score 0):

What about this one [PHP Error Handler](https://github.com/JosephLenton/PHP-Error/)